# error storing < and > characters in app.config file in C#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, configuration-files, configurationmanager

I want to store a sql query in app.config file which has < and >
characters but file shows error 'expecting >' ,
have you come across this problem ?

Comment: @ChrisBrint what if I wish to change that query in between after launching application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;.`

Answer (score 3):

If you indeed need to put that query in the app.config, you can put it inside a CDATA section or you can escape those characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're storing SQL in the app.config you're probably doing something wrong. As @ChrisBint said, you should probably put this in an embedded resource file instead.

That being said, you should be able to correct the problem by replacing any special characters with a proper entity:

```
<  ... &lt;
>  ... &gt;

"  ... &quot;
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the SQL in a resource file rather than the app.config.

Answer (score 1):

> (greater-than character) use "&gt"

Must be used for an attribute value, but > is acceptable as the content of an element as long as < does not precede it.

< (less-than character) - use "&lt"

Must be used for an attribute value, but < is acceptable as the content of an element as long as > does not follow it.

source - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to use XML Encoded characters. `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>` respectively

This should ensure any special character will be handled correctly in the xml and be returned as expected